# How to add new users in existing user db having no-email when coming from log in from facebook

Tags: php, facebook, email, facebook-graph-api

i have users login/signup system and DB to store their info in place,
now i am integrating **log in from facebook** in my site.

i came to know , that not all fb users have **email addresses** some have mobile numbers as email address and those arent passed via oauth system, so no email value is passed after user log in using facebook.,

so how am i supposed to add him in my existing system where everthing is based on userid and email. ?

if no email is found on fb acocunt , should i ask user to enter email address after they have granted permission on facebook page, . but what if some people dont have email addresses at all.?

whats the best way to achieve this ?

allow users to **log in using facebook** and still be a part of my existing users system ?

Comment: Best way is to not require email and just use the id that Facebook sends you back

Comment: @WizKid thats great thikning but should i create new table for users coming from fb ?